# How to sort / re-arrange / shift JS array objects without changing original positioning

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of

```
let arr = [
{workoutName : 'push-up'},
{workoutName : 'plank'},
{workoutName : 'single-Leg (Left)'},
{workoutName : 'arm-extend (Right)'},
{workoutName : 'Jumping Jack'},
{workoutName : 'single-Leg (Right)'},
{workoutName : 'something (Left)'},
{workoutName : 'arm-extend (Left)'},
{workoutName : 'somethingElse'},
{workoutName : 'something (Right)'}

]
```

I would like to sort / shift the original objects to match their pairs if available in this list and keep the positioning. Like shifting the names around without breaking the current structure.

This does sort it but I need to keep the same order.

```
let sorted = arr.sort( function( a , b){
    if(a.workoutName > b.workoutName) return 1;
    if(a.workoutName < b.workoutName) return -1;
    return 0;
});

console.log(sorted);
Array [ Object { workoutName: "Jumping Jack" }, 
    Object { workoutName: "arm-extend (Right)" }, 
    Object { workoutName: "arm-extend (Left)" }, 
    Object { workoutName: "plank" }, 
    Object { workoutName: "push-up" }, 
    Object { workoutName: "single-Leg (Left)" }, 
    Object { workoutName: "single-Leg (Right)" }, 
    Object { workoutName: "something (Left)" }, 
    Object { workoutName: "something (Right)" }, 
    Object { workoutName: "somethingElse" }
]
```

expected result

```
[
{workoutName : 'push-up'},
{workoutName : 'plank'},
{workoutName : 'single-Leg (Left)'},
{workoutName : 'single-Leg (Right)'},
{workoutName : 'arm-extend (Right)'},
{workoutName : 'arm-extend (Left)'},
{workoutName : 'Jumping Jack'},
{workoutName : 'something (Left)'},
{workoutName : 'something (Right)'}
{workoutName : 'somethingElse'},
]
```

Comment: which elements should keep the position or order? what do you mean with sorting?

Comment: So you want to sort without sorting? I'm confused ...

Comment: You want to move the objects into sequential groups by the first occurrence of `workoutName`?

Comment: yes @Teemu, I may have described my initial question as to how to sort but it 's more like shifting elements without breaking the original order.

Comment: @NinaScholz , I have updated my question. Shifting the position rather than simple sorting

Comment: *" shifting elements without breaking the original order"* - still doesn't make sense, sorry.  Either you want to move elements around, or not. Maybe you want to sort a copy of the array, and keep the original?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group by the first part of `workoutName` and get grouped items in order as flat array.

```js
const
    array = [{ workoutName: 'push-up' }, { workoutName: 'plank' }, { workoutName: 'single-Leg (Left)' }, { workoutName: 'arm-extend (Right)' }, { workoutName: 'Jumping Jack' }, { workoutName: 'single-Leg (Right)' }, { workoutName: 'something (Left)' }, { workoutName: 'arm-extend (Left)' }, { workoutName: 'somethingElse' }, { workoutName: 'something (Right)' }],
    order = { left: 1, right: 2 },
    sortReplace = s => s.replace(/^.*?(\((left|right)\))*$/i, (_, __, side = '') => order[side.toLowerCase()] || 0),
    sortSide = (a, b) => sortReplace(a.workoutName) - sortReplace(b.workoutName),
    getGroup = s => s.match(/.*?(?=(\s\(|$))/)?.[0] || '',
    result = Object
        .values(array.reduce((r, o) => {
            const group = getGroup(o.workoutName);
            if ((r[group] = r[group] || []).push(o) > 1) {
                r[group].sort(sortSide);
            }
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .flat();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina, code runs perfectly fine on front end but node js  doesn't seem to like it :) throwing error "??=" unexpected identifier

Comment: it looks like an older js version. please see workaround.

Comment: you can change the order by changing the object `order`. please see edit.